# Find the real and imaginary parts of $f(z)=\frac{2}{z+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find the real and imaginary parts of $f(z)=\frac{2}{z+i}$.

Denote the conjugate of $z$ as $\bar{z}$, then

$f(z)=\frac{2(\bar{z}-i)}{(z+i)(\bar{z}-i)}=\frac{2(\bar{z}-i)}{|{z}|^2+1}=\frac{2x-2yi-2}{x^2+y^2+1}=\frac{2x-2}{x^2+y^2+1} + \frac{2yi}{x^2+y^2+1}$

So the real portion is $Re(f(z))=\frac{2x-2}{x^2+y^2+1}$ and the imaginary part is $Im(f(z))=\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+1}$.

Are there any errors in either calculation or notation?

Comment: Somewhere in the middle you moved from $-2yi$ to $+2yi$. Otherwise ok.

Answer (score 1):

It was $-2yi$ and you made it $+2yi$. This is your mistake, the rest are fine and the notation is just as fine.  It's just the imaginary fraction that has a minus in front of it.